# How do I use Logical Operators like AND or OR in Liferay 7 Search?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I would like to create a liferay search that recognizes logical operators like

- AND

  OR

  NOT

Can anyone tell me where to start ?

Best regards,

Daniel

Comment: In what context?  Like a search in the code using DynamicQuery?  A search portlet configuration to define the results to include?  A JSP <liferay-ui:search-container /> tag to find entities for display? Etc.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Just looking for samples or documentation is an explicit reason for closing a question on stackoverflow - please add some code that can be worked on and that demonstrated you're not only asking for the docs. This will also neatly answer @dnebing's question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use eleasticsearch API approach. elasticsearch listens to port 9200 when you start liferay.

try : http://localhost:9200/_search?q=$queryterm

Now you can use the power of elasticsearch to pass your queries.

HTH

Sharan

Comment: This'd be a good answer in the elasticsearch realm - however in Liferay, it results in different facets, in permissions to documents being checked, and uses an API that transparently covers this.